# How to access contact ID and checksum for a new contact from the Caldera form that creates the contact?

Tags: wordpress, checksum, caldera-forms

Using a Drupal webform I can create a new Civi contact, and get the contact ID and checksum for that contact from the form submission, enabling me to use it in an email triggered by the form submission. This lets me send a link to a second form, passing the contact id and checksum in the URL, to pre-populate the second form with details of the newly created contact.

I'd like to do the same thing using Caldera forms on Wordpress, but I'm struggling to see whether, and if yes, how, that might work. Can anyone cast any light?

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of how to do the second part of this in the [integration module's README](https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm).

> Checksum support to auto-populate form with URLs like example.com/some-page?cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}

The part I'm not aware of is how to properly redirect from one form to a second form with the right contact ID and checksum. I don't have any Civi-on-WordPress instances to test with.